# Question about a separation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

This theorem is called the Kreps-Yan theorem. I have just a small question about the proof. We have a probability space given. The statement is:

> Let $p\in [1,\infty]$, $q$ the conjugate. Suppose $C\subset L^p$ a convex cone, which is closed in the weak topology (for $p=\infty$ it is the weak-star topology), $C\supset-L^p_+:=\{f\in L^p:f\ge 0\}$ and $C\cap L^p_+=\{0\}$. Then there exists a equivalent measure $Q$ with density $\frac{dQ}{dP}\in L^q$ such that $E_Q[f]\le 0\forall f\in C$.

Outline of the proof is: for every $x\in L^p_+\backslash \{0\}$ we can separate this from $C$, i.e. it exists a $z_x\in L^q$ such that

$$E[z_x x]\ge a > b\ge E[z_xf]$$
for all $f\in C$. Using cone property one can prove that $b=0$ and $E[z_x]>0$. Using Halmos-Savage theorem, on can prove that there is a countable collection $(z_{x_i})$ such that $P[\cup\{z_{x_i}>0\}]=1$. Then one defines

$$z:=\sum_{i\ge 1}2^{-i}z_{x_i}$$

W.l.o.g we can assume $\|z_{x_i}\|_q=1$, hence $z\in L^q$. But why is $E[z]=1$, which is needed. Or how can I modify the $z_{x_i}'s$ to guarantee that?

Comment: Why can't we rescale $z$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo The problem is: If $\|z_{x_i}\|_q=1$, then $\|z\|_q\le 1$. But I do not see exactly, why $E[z]=\sum 2^{-i}E[z_{x_i}]$ should be finite? If I would scale the $z_{x_i}$ in such a way, taht $E[z_{x_i}]=1$, this would be clear. But of course, I can not assume $E[z_{x_i}]=1=\|z_{x_i}\|_q$ both at the same time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $E[z_{x_i}]$ is positive, we have $E[z]>0$. We thus can consider $z':=\frac 1{E[z]}z$, an element of $L^q$ which has expectation $1$.

Comment: Sorry but I have a question. Using monotone convergence, we know: $E[z]=\sum 2^{-i}E[z_{x_i}]$. Why is the latter sum finite?

Comment: Compare with the $L^q$ norm of $x_i$.

Comment: ah sorry, $E[z_{x_i}]=Q(\Omega)=1$, right?